# Is there a way to use NUnit parameterized testing to specify object fields to check in C#?

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm writing some tests against an API using NUnit, and have encountered an issue where I'd like to utilize parameterized testing to check the attributes of a return object one by one using a single test method, but cannot find how to specify and then access the specific fields in question.

That is, if I have the following class:

```cs
public class Person{  
     string name { get; set; }
     int age { get; set; }
     string occupation { get; set; }
     int id { get; set; }  
}
```

and an API get_person/id that returns a JSON package that I deserialze into this object, I would like to be able to write the following NUnit test:

```cs
[Test]
[TestCase("name", 1)]
[TestCase("age", 1)]
[TestCase("occupation", 1)]
public void GetPersonShouldReturnIndicatedAttributes(string field, int id){
     //Arrange
     string attributes = "?&attributes=" + field;
     var client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(api_url + "/get_person/" + id + attributes);
     //Act
     HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress).Result;
     var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     var resultPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(resultBody);
     //Assert  
     Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     Assert.That(resultPerson.field, Is.EqualTo(ExpectedValuesPerson.field);
}
```

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to parameterize the field selection of the Person object - but obviously doing resultPerson.field is not valid. Is there a valid way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use reflection to check the value of the **property** name you pass to the test

Comment: @Travis_at_sicura If you've successfully solved the problem on your own, please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @stuartd for reminding me about reflection (it's been a few years since I've written in C#), here's the solution:

```cs
[Test]
[TestCase("name", 1)]
[TestCase("age", 1)]
[TestCase("occupation", 1)]
public void GetPersonShouldReturnIndicatedAttributes(string field, int id){
     //Arrange
     string attributes = "?&attributes=" + field;
     var client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(api_url + "/get_person/" + id + attributes);
     //Act
     HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress).Result;
     var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     var resultPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(resultBody);
     PropertyInfo fieldPropertyInfo = resultPerson.GetType().GetProperty(field);
     //Assert  
     Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     Assert.That(fieldPropertyInfo.GetValue(resultPerson), Is.EqualTo(fieldPropertyInfo.GetValue(ExpectedValuesPerson));
}
```